# Facebook login implementation for android using MVP patttern

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-login, mvp

I need to implement facebook login in my app using Model-View-Presenter (MVP) pattern but the problem really is how to avoid injecting my presenter with a reference to an Activity (which would be negating MVP pattern since a presenter should not contain platform components).

`LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));`

As can be seen above, the `logInWithReadPermissins()` function takes as an argument a reference to an activity.

Answer (score 1):

In this repository they pose a good solution.

https://github.com/SergeyBurlaka/Android-MVP-FacebookSDK-GoogleAPI-SocialViewer-App

and the execution would be something like that

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions((Activity) view,
            Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));
```

in kotlin

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(view as Activity,
            Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"))
```